# JavaFX not found by FindBugs analysis (Eclipse plugin)

Tags: java, javafx, classpath, findbugs

The Eclipse plugin for FindBugs seems to have problems to find special Java libraries like JavaFX (and others) although they should be on the classpath according to the Eclipse project configuration.

**Example:** When you create a JavaFX project in Eclipse (`File -> New -> Other... -> JavaFX -> JavaFX Project`), under `<Project> -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries` there's usually an item `JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.X]` (where `X` is the version, e.g. 8). When you expand this item, you should see that `lib/ext/jfxrt.jar` (the JAR for JavaFX) is included.

I set up FindBugs for the project as follows:

1. Enable project specific settings
2. Minimum rank: `20`
3. Minimum confidence: `Low`
4. Make sure that category `Correctness` is checked
5. Activate the hidden detector `ResolveAllReferences` (Pattern `VR`)

When building the project to perform FindBugs analysis, the list of found bugs includes a `Unresolvable reference to javafx.XYZ ...` bug for every reference to a JavaFX class.

However, if you put you Java version's `jfxrt.jar` on the classpath as external JAR (additional to being implicit on the CP through the `JRE System Library...` item), FindBugs shows no JavaFX-related `Unresolvable reference...` bugs.

**Questions:**

1. Why can't FindBugs find the implicitly included `jfxrt.jar`?
2. Is there a solution for the problem that can cope with different kinds of systems working on the project as well as probably slightly different Java 8 versions on these systems?
   With this last remark I want to suggest that putting the libraries in question into the project's `lib` folder might not be a good solution.